Issue calling cpdef function in jupyter notebook
I am trying to use cython in a jupyter notebook but am running into some issues. I have one cell with the following
%%cython --compile-args=-fopenmp --link-args=-fopenmp --verbose --force
cimport cython
import numpy as np
from cython.parallel cimport prange
cimport scipy.linalg.cython_lapack as lapack
import numpy as np
from libc.math cimport exp

cpdef double complex ensemble(p, double df):
    ....
    return(....)

This cell seems to compile fine but in the following cell,
print(ensemble(p,df))

gives an error
NameError: name 'ensemble' is not defined

I have tried creating a wrapper in python to call the cython functions rather than using cpdef but still have the same error.
